# Getting You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type in react.js app

Tags: reactjs, babel-loader

I am building an react app. but running the code i am getting You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders.

```
`return (
    <div className="h-[500px] bg-red-900 border-2 rounded-lg">   
    </div>
)`
```

I create .babelrc file in root directory with the following code inside it.

`{ "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"] }`